# Cannot get Jquery autocomplete to work in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, autocomplete

I cannot get autocomplete to work. I suspect this is because of my declaration of the URL in the Jquery method. How can I fix this issue?

This is the method in the HomeController:

```
   public JsonResult Autocomplete(string term)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbintegroModelContext"].ConnectionString;
            List<string> CompanyName = new List<string>();
            string query = string.Format("select distinct CompanyName from CompanyTable where CompanyName like '%{0}%'", term);
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        CompanyName.Add(reader["CompanyName"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(CompanyName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

this is the Index view:

```
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CompanyName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var param = { companyName: $('#CompanyName').val() };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Home")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                        alert(err.Message)
                        console.log("Ajax Error!");
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2 //min legth of textbox input
        });
    });
    </script>
```

...later on in the same view I have the html helper textbox CompanyName.

```
 @Html.TextBox("CompanyName", null, new { @class = "indexTextbox" })
```

Comment: Try changing the type to 'GET' in your ajax call, are you getting the response back? console.log might help in reviewing what response you are getting back on ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried re-creating this problem on my end. 
Have you used your browser's code inspector to see if any errors are returned?

Also you may try placing the jquery code inside a $(document).ready() function to see if that helps.

Comment: I've changed it to this and renamed the jsonresult in the home controller to Autocomplete. Still not working! :(


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("'CompanyName").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("Autocomplete")'
            });
        });
    </script>